# Any good javascript range highlighter

Tags: javascript, plugins, highlight

I have been struggling for a long time looking for a range highlighter. If the user selects a particular text, that should be highlighted and in the same way if the use selects a range of text and click on remove highlight it should remove only the highlight from that selection. Please help me , i am stuck with this for a long time . Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you want to add a button so that your selection (the text you highlighted) becomes unselected when you click the button?

Answer (score 0):

You don't exactly need a plugin to do this, instead, you can get the element for where you the selected/highlighted text is, and then stored its content in a variable. Then you can set the elements `.innerHTML` back to the stored value. In the example below I have applied this to the entire body so it removed any selections made on the entire webpage.

See working example below:

```js
const btn = _ => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('body');
  const txt = elem.innerHTML;
  elem.textContent = '';
  elem.innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="txt">This is some text. This is some more text, this is even mooooore text, this is even mooooore text, this is even mooooore text, this is even mooooore text, this is even mooooore text! this is even mooooore text! this is even mooooore text!</p>
  <button onclick="btn()">Deselect</button>

</body>
```